# PHP Function kills Apache after execution time

Tags: php

I have written a PHP Function which is called by every Visitor but I read from the Logs that especially a Dynamic Page can't be open and kills after a while Apache and the access to the Website is down (Error 502). I removed the Function and the page worked without a Problem.

The Function to short URLs is like here:

```
function shortyourls(){
    global $smarty;

    // Inputs
    $shorturl   =   'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $signature  =   "123567890";
    $siteurl    =   "http://doma.in";
    $format     =   "json";
    $Artikel    =   $smarty->get_template_vars('Artikel');
    $title      =   http_build_query(array('title' => $Artikel->cName));
    $keyword        = substr(str_shuffle("123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 8, 8);


    // Phases url
    $short = file_get_contents($siteurl.'/yourls-api.php?signature='.$signature.'&action=shorturl&url='.$shorturl.'&format='.$format.'&keyword='.$keyword.'&'.$title);

    $url=json_decode($short,TRUE);
    $output = $url['shorturl'];
    echo $output;

    }
```

How could I solve this Problem? It should not reach the max_execution_time.

Comment: Sorry thinking too much and writing same time is a problem.. can't open and kills.

Comment: what happens when you access to your built url `$siteurl.'/yourls-api.php?signature='.$signature.'&action=shorturl&url='.$shorturl.'&format='.$format.'&keyword='.$keyword.'&'.$title` directly from your web browser ?

Comment: after how much time ?

Comment: Try increase `set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` for php and check if it works, as said before, it seems a `file_get_contents()` problem.